# access form elements from a non wicket field

Tags: javascript, forms, wicket

I'm trying to access a form value that isn't a wicket component and I'm not sure how to do it.

I have a TextField firstName, TextField lastname and I'm getting a value from javascript that I want to pass to the onSubmit form of my page but I'm not sure how to access it.

or maybe I can get the value another way.

Here is the portion of the code

```
<script type="IN/Login"> 
<input type="hidden" name="linkedin-id" value="<?js= id ?>" wicket:id="hidden" />
</script>
```

I'm assuming because the wicket:id is in the script tag and it thinks I haven't added the component to the html page.

All I am trying to do is pass the id into the "onSubmit" method in my wicket form.

any help would be appreciated. I'm really new to javascript so it seems that this would be easy to do. I just haven't been able to see it

Comment: Ok I think I figured it out. I changed script tag above as:

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, started to post in comment above. I figured it out I think. I changed it to as follows.

```
<script type="IN/Login"> 
<input type="hidden" name="linkedin-id" value="<?js= id ?>" />
</script>
```

and in my onSubmit

```
Request request = getRequest();
IRequestParameters irp = request.getPostParameters();
System.out.println("link id " + irp.getParameterValue("linkedin-id"));
```